# foreach row in datatable add a asptablerow and asptablecell for each column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Im trying to programatically add rows to a asp:table below are my efforts thus far:-

but datarow does not contain a getenumorator, i dont know what this means, can anyone help me out?

i know using a repeater is easier but for this page i need a serverside table so im trying to do it this way, also how do i add the column data in the right order to match the tableheaders?

```
dtEquipment = new dsData.tblEquipmentDataTable();
taEquipment = new dsDataTableAdapters.tblEquipmentTableAdapter();
taEquipment.FillbyUser(dtEquipment);

foreach (DataRow DRow in dtEquipment)
{
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
    foreach (DataColumn dCol in DRow)
    {
        TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
        tCell.Text = DRow["AssetNo"].ToString();
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
    }
    tblTest.Rows.Add(tRow);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the [`DataTable.Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx) property and the [`DataTable.Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) property:

```
foreach (DataRow DRow in dtEquipment.Rows)
{
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
    foreach (DataColumn dCol in dtEquipment.Columns)
    {
        // ...
        tCell.Text = DRow[dCol].ToString();
        // ...
    }
    tblTest.Rows.Add(tRow);
}
```

Comment: my error is here foreach (DataColumn dCol in DRow) below that (although you prob fixed that bit too

Comment: @AlexW: What does that mean? I'm using a loop to create one TableRow for each DataRow, then i'm using a loop to create one `TableCell` for each DataColumn which is added to the TableRow. This is added to an `ASP.NET` Table `tblTest` which declaration you haven't shown.

Comment: sorry see edit above, im getting all columns when i only need ones that match the tableheadercells... if possible? this may be a new question?